# Generic Hp LaserJet 1012 Printer Drivers For Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer, compatibility, hp-laserjet

I've recently upgraded a machine to Windows 7 x64. This machine has a 1012 printer attached. According to HP's site, the printer is no going to be supported in Windows 7. Are there generic drivers that may suffice?

Is there even such a thing as a generic printer driver?

Comment: Curious to see if anyone has a solution, I'm having trouble as well with 64 bit Windows and HP printers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Low-end HP printers (ie: Home-use ones) are ['host-based'](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/H/host_based_printer.html)-only printers.  Meaning they use the computer's CPU to do the printing processing, and require a specific driver to do it.  This keeps the price low, but the major trade-off is (as you've discovered) when the printer gets end-of-life'd by the manufacturer they stop making drivers, and the printers aren't compatible with any other drivers.

You can try the HP ["universal" printer driver](http://h20338.www2.hp.com/Hpsub/cache/344252-0-0-225-121.html), but the 1012 isn't on the supported printer list, and from trying to get 1012's working with Vista in the past personally, it's not going to happen (even with a hacked apart XP driver), especially when you throw 64-bit into the mix.

Bascially, if you buy a sub-$200 laser printer, expect to replace it whenever you replace your OS with something a couple years newer than the printer.  :)

If you want to keep the same printer for years and years, and have the most compatibility regardless of system, then aim for a printer that uses the [PCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Command_Language) and/or [Postscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) printer languages.

Sorry I don't have better news.

Comment: +1 Same experience here.  Printer was cheap and cheerful at the time but support for new OSs is poor and that can be expected for sub $200 unit

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the HP LJ 1012 is a "host-based" printer meaning that the print processing is done *mostly* on the PC.  It doesn't use Postscript or PCL5/6 as the printing language but uses a propietary printing language.  That makes it hard to use another driver to talk to it.

As techie007 just said, HP's Universal Print Driver (UPD) does not support host-based printers like this.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues with HP 1012, the driver was simply never made for Win7 64bit. I used the driver for another HP LaserJet

Anyway, the solution was to use the "HP Universal printing PCL 5" driver for windows 7, found on: [HP driver site - universal driver](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/ProductList.jsp?locale=en_US&taskId=135&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=503548)

simple as could be: pick your OS
 page 1) HP Universal Print Driver for Windows 64-bit PCL 5
 page 2) Microsoft Windows 7 (64-bit)
 page 3) 3 - HP Universal Print Driver for Windows PCL5 
Download, install make it default printer and it works!

Answer (score 1):

The LaserJet 1015 drivers seem to work just fine.

- Under "Devices and Printers", choose "Add a printer"
- You will most likely need to press the "Windows Update" button to get an updated list
- Choose HP LaserJet 1015
- If given the option, choose to *replace* the existing driver
- Print a test page

Answer (score 0):

I just posted on similar subject here: [HP 3015, Win 7](https://superuser.com/questions/253853/printer-driver-for-windows-7/430536#430536), I resolved the same issue with my HP1010 with universal PCL driver and Windows 7, 64bit. Also it's shared to 32bit Windows 7 machines in LAN.