# Printer driver for windows 7

Tags: drivers

I just installed windows 7 ultimate, but i cannot get my HP 3015 Laserjet all in one to work. Are there any drivers available, the driver given on the HP website does not work. Please, help.

Comment: Which driver did you use? What did not work exactly? Did the installation procedure fail? Could it detect the printer? Provide more details, otherwise no one can help.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with HP 1010, the driver was simply never made for Win7. I used the driver for another HP LaserJet, the HP 3055 instead original one and it kind of worked but I had issues connecting other machines to it through LAN.

Anyway, the solution was to use the "HP Universal printing PCL 5" driver for windows 7, found on: [HP driver site - universal driver](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/ProductList.jsp?locale=en_US&taskId=135&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=503548)

With that, it works best so far. There is still an issue after each 10-15 or so pages are printed, with printer just printing the "unsupported personality pcl" or something like that, but I can live with that.

BTW, I installed this HP1010 with universal printer at Win7 64bit and also made it work as shared printer at remote Win7 32bit machines (by including x86 drivers too in 64bit driver).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you're having problems with the default Windows 7 driver for the 3015?  Or that a driver for the 3015 isn't included by default?

For my LaserJet 3200, I seem to recall that the 3200 wasn't included out of the box with Win7.  I tried drivers from HP's website, then finally found this simple procedure worked:

```
-Start
-Devices and Printers
-Add a printer
-Add a local printer
-Use an existing port
-Click on Windows Update (wait a minute or two for it to update)
-Check the list to see if the 3015 is now there (in my case it wasn't there originally and then appeared after the update)
-Add it as you normally would.
```